# Google keep blocking our app login

Tags: authentication

I'm developing a contest platform using Youtube. 
So each contestant will upload a video thru our website. The video will be uploaded to our specific channel.
But, I kept receive warn email, google block login attempt from our contestant. The email says something that an unsecure app tryin to login.
And our tester (contestant) always failed to upload their video.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can approach this:

- You can [share a Youtube Channel](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4642409?hl=en). To do this, you need to have all the users as a manager of the G+ page the channel is connected to.
- You can give all the users your account credentials for them to upload to your channel
  your channel.
- You can have the users upload the video to your servers and then you upload each video on the Channel's account yourself.
- You can have them upload it to their own Youtube Channel and they can just pass you the URL to the video.

Personally, I think the last option is best.

For your login issue, if you are having users use the account credentials to login and upload themselves, you may be getting that warning because too many users from too many different locations are trying to access the same one account.